# Can we use are with prural

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct ?

1. Pets for children are advantageous.
2. Pets for children is advantageous.

Which one is correct (Grows vs grow)?

1. Children who grows in presence of pets are empathetic.
2. Children who grow in presence of pets are empathetic.

What is the difference between illustrates and illustrate ?

Please clarify!

Comment: Note that for your second example, you should use the "phrasal verb" form ***to grow up*** (what children are doing while they mature / develop into adults). Plus you need the definite article before "presence", so it's *Children who **grow up** in **the** presence of pets are empathetic.*

Answer (score -1):

[Verbs should agree with the noun's number](https://www.esc.edu/online-writing-center/resources/grammar/nouns-verbs/basic-noun-verb-agreement/).

Pets (plural) for children are (plural) advantageous.

Children (plural) who grow (plural) in presence of pets are empathetic.

> What is the difference between illustrates and illustrate ?

He/she/it illustrates.

I/you/we/they illustrate.

[It is basic conjugation](https://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/illustrate).